# A simple example for implementing OAuth2.0

Tags: java, oauth

I want to build my project using OAuth2.0,i have read the example page by url:https://bitbucket.org/smartproject/oauth-2.0/wiki/Home.When i run the Oauth-demo by Github，an error message with 404 returned by setting redirect URi to http://localhost:8080/myproject/redirect. I have no idea what I can do and I am wonder who can give me some hints or a simple example including client and authorization server.

Answer (score 3):

Spring security supports oauth 1.0 and 2.0

[oauth example code](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/devguide)

this should help

Answer (score 2):

If you are use to use Spring and Jersey, this is a very good starting point, using the  [Spring Security OAuth2 implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/)

I personally do not recommend Amber because is in a very early state and their development goes too sluggish.

Comment: The second link there is dead

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [OAuth2 Client-Demo](https://github.com/apache/oltu/tree/amber-0.10/oauth-2.0/oauth2-client-demo) wich uses Apache Oltu.

Comment: Thank you so much,i had download the client-demo,but I don't know how to implement it....

Comment: Can we have the simplest example of oauth 2 please